# Unable to reference HttpContext.SignInAsync using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .net core 2.0.1 app that uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstraction` assembly. In the app I'm referencing an extension method, `SignInAsync` from the `AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions` class. This is perfect!

However I've created a new application using .net core 2.0.3 and it seems that Microsoft have decided to remove the `AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions` class from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstraction` assembly. I can't seem to find any links on the net that shows me what new package I need to reference. What's the work around from using `await httpContext.SignInAsync()`

I have a service that doesn't reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.All. It's an .NET CORE application with the following code:

```
public async Task SignInAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Guid userId, bool isPersistent = false)
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(userId), CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await httpContext.SignInAsync(
      CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }
    );
}
```

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies\2.0.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer\2.0.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\2.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.identitymodel.tokens\5.1.4\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt\5.1.4\lib\netstandard1.4\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**UPDATE:**

The class `AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions` was not removed (sorry Microsoft). A hard-coded path to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` was being used instead of referencing the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions`. This lead to the confusion as I had reference to the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication but no reference to the extension class that I was looking for.

Comment: Are you sure? .NET Core itself doesn't contain anything specific to *ASP.NET Core*, it's the runtime. Which *package* are you using? Which version?

Comment: BTW [the method is still there](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L112). It's not just [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0) that show it, it's in the source code itself. Did you miss a reference perhaps?

Comment: "I have a service that doesn't live inside an ASP.NET application", then why are you using ASP.NET Core code? How is it not an ASP.NET Core application?  I think you are very confused between .NET Core and ASP.NET Core

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry, I should reword this. What I mean to say is that I'm not making use of the asp.net template i.e. I'm not using that full Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package. Tbh I could have just used .Net Standard but because of referencing issues between some of my projects I needed to convert to .netcoreapp. But my question is why is it that I'm unable to reference AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions class using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstraction library

Comment: @Met-u no repro. The method is in the library. I can use it just fine in a .NET Core Console project after adding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions` package, v 2.0.3

Comment: Yes, you will need to [edit] your question to make it much more clear than it currently is. Also, copy your .csproj so we can see your actual references

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's really odd because my intellisense is complaining and I'm referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication. The only difference I can see between my old project and my new one is that the fixed one is using version 2.0.1 and the broken one is using 2.0.3

Comment: @Met-u referencing an assembly or a package? The extension method is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Abstractions` anyway, not `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication`. Besides, which *package version* are you using? The *runtime* has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Met-u create a new .NET Core console application and add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" Version="2.0.3" />`. Compare *that* with your project. BTW there's no `.NET Core 2.0.1` or 2.0.3. All applications are `2.0`, ie they have `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>` in csproj

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm referring to the assembly version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions

Comment: @Met-u and yes, the method is there. In the *package*. You hard-coded references to the fallback location used when offline instead. Remove *all* of them and add the packages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I created a new .NET console app and you absolutely right, the class and method I'm looking for is there. I was able to resolve my issue by removing the HintPath reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` and just adding `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" Version="2.0.3" />`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can post your comment for removing the hard-coded references and rather using the package reference and I'll be happy to accept it as an answer as it resolve my issue. The hardcoded reference mislead me as I still had reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` but was unable to reference the extension class with the same namespace.